# killer of kings

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

> The death cap mushroom (Amanita phalloides), which has been the
> ‘**killer of kings**’ for centuries, could be losing its edge. Scientists
> have found a possible antidote for the deadly mushroom’s toxin.

[Source: Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-01630-9)

I don't quite understand the meaning of "killer of kings", which seems to have two possible different meanings to me:

(1) It means it is in particular a killer who kills king  of a country. The killer doesn't kill other people except kings.

(2) It means the king of kings of killer countries (supposed that a country are completely comprised of killers and so there is a killer king; now "killer of kings" means the king of kings of such countries).

I am not sure which is the correct answer (it can be both are incorrect).

Comment: The article cited gives two example of the mushroom killing "kings"  - actually  emperors .

Comment: Both your answers are incorrect. The mushroom has famously been used on some occasions in history to poison a king.

Comment: #2 doesn't make sense, because that's not how English word order works.  "An Xer of Ys" means "Someone who performs the action X on Ys."

Comment: @stangdon 13  Please make your reply an answer, which is exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English, ***verb*er of *noun*** generally means someone or something who performs the action X on Y.  For example,

- a farmer of corn: a person who grows corn
- a slayer of giants: a person who slays giants
- a singer of songs: a person who sings songs

It does not necessarily mean that this is the only thing they do - a *killer of kings* is someone or something that kills kings, although it might do other things too.

Sometimes it is a little ambiguous: **the killer of the desert** probably means "a killer *from* or *in* the desert", not "someone who kills the desert".

---

If you want meaning #2, you would have to reverse the word order: a **king of killers** would mean a king who rules over a country of killers, or metaphorically the chief, most important killer.